# Which process/daemon replaces netplugd in Centos 7.1?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, networking

I'm moving a piece of software from Ubuntu 12.04 to Centos 7.1. Part of the original installation script runs dpkg -i netplug_1.2.9.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb.

I can't install a ubuntu deb on Centos, nor can I find netplug for Centos 7 anywhere. From the looks of it on google and forums, netplug is an old old solution to a now day-to-day problem (ethernet hotplug detection and up/downing interfaces accordingly).

My question is - Which process/daemon replaces netplugd in Centos 7.1? I know that in Centos 7.1 we have ethernet hotpluging - what part of the system takes care of it?

Thanks

EDIT: and how would I go about configuring it (netplug has a nifty netplug.conf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be [NetworkManager,](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager) split in several RPMs (listed in this [bug description](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8391)):

```
# find CENTOS7.1/ | grep NetworkManager | grep -v i686
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-tui-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-glib-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-libreswan-0.9.8.0-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-wifi-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-bluetooth-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-wwan-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-libnm-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-team-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
CENTOS7.1/Packages/NetworkManager-adsl-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

The actual daemon is in [NetworkManager-1.0.0](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/7.1.1503/x86_64/Packages/NetworkManager-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.html)

Comment: Cheers Dan, could you give a pointer on how to modify settings for the hotplugging (where are the conf files, if any?)

Comment: I never had to modify the files directly (I'm using opensuse). This seems to cover configuration: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/SystemSettings